# How to send an array of objects using react hook form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-hook-form

my useForm hook looks like this :

```
const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      target: "",
      value: "",
      PlanProduct: [
       
      ],
    },
  });
```

I'm trying to send 3 objects inside my plan product with specific values

so for example it should look like this :

```
PlanProducts : [
{
createdBy: ""
createdDate : "" } ,
 
{
createdBy: ""
createdDate : "" }
,
{
createdBy: ""
createdDate : ""  } ,

]
```

my input field looks like this :

```
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
<Controller
              name="target"
              control={control}
              rules={{ required: "Cost is required" }}
              render={({
                field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name, ref },
              }) => (
                <TextField
                  variant="outlined"
                  placeholder="Cost"
                  inputRef={ref}
                  sx={{
                    backgroundColor: "ghostWhite",
                    boxShadow: "0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
                    height: "35px",
                    display: "flex",
                    alignItems: "start",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    borderRadius: "20px",
                    flexGrow: "1",
                    color: "black",
                    marginTop: "18px",
                    width: {
                      xs: "100%",
                      md: "auto",
                    },
                    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
                      border: 0,
                      boxShadow: "unset",
                      width: "100%",
                    },
                    "& .MuiInputBase-colorPrimary": {
                      border: 0,
                      boxShadow: "unset",
                    },
                    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-input": {
                      paddingTop: 0,
                      paddingBottom: 0,
                      display: "flex",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      border: "0",
                    },
                    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
                      border: 0,
                    },
                    "& .MuiInputLabel-root": {
                      fontFamily: "Overpass",
                    },
                  }}
                  value={value}
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
              )}
            />

          </form>
```

I'm using the controller component for the form to work with react hook form ,  How am i supposed to represent an array of 3 objects inside my original form and let the value be inside my planProduct array ?

Ask me questions if it's not clear

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding of your provided code, it seems like you are not registering your textFields to be completely controlled by react-hook-form, here's the source you can go through in order to find out in-depth:
https://youtu.be/EbFW3u44xiY?si=Vbec1AIg39bcd-GC

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).